# Handling CancellationToken from different class

Tags: c#, cancellation

I have a class like so:

```
public class FtpTaskVideo : IFtpTask
{
    //some fields
    public CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private Panel CreatePanel(string text, int count, int value)
    {
        Panel pnlOutput = new Panel();
        pnlOutput.Name = "pnlInfo";
        pnlOutput.AutoSize = true;
        pnlOutput.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        //adding some controls

        Button btnUserCancel = new Button();
        btnUserCancel.Name = "btnUserCancel";
        btnUserCancel.AutoSize = true;
        btnUserCancel.Text = "Stop";
        btnUserCancel.Click += new EventHandler(btnUserCancel_Click);
        pnlOutput.Controls.Add(btnUserCancel);
        btnUserCancel.BringToFront();

        return pnlOutput;
    }

    public void btnUserCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tokenSource.Cancel();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
         //some code
        while(somethingToDownload)
        {
         var task = Task<SharedConstants.downloadFtpFileStatus>.Factory.StartNew(() => dff.Download(tokenSource.Token), tokenSource.Token);
         try
         {
             downloadStatus = task.Result;
         }
         catch (System.AggregateException exc)
         {
               //do something                 
         }
         //some code
        }
}
```

And in the second class (dff):

```
public Shared.Classes.SharedConstants.downloadFtpFileStatus Download(CancellationToken token)
{
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return Shared.Classes.SharedConstants.downloadFtpFileStatus.CANCELLED;               
    }
    else //do some stuff
}
```

Now, I have another class, which dff is an instance of and Download is it's method. One of the things dff does is update and redraw the panel according to the data it gets during Download method operation. How, after it draws a button and I press it can I send the cancel token back to original class to stop it from downloading?

Comment: Why do you need to send the token back? Both `FtpTaskVideo` and `dff` seem to be using the same token already.

Comment: @Enigmativity maybe I don't understand it well, since it's the frist time I'm using it, but my question is: Class DFF has 2 methods - Download and RedrawPanel. Download accepts CancellationToken as parameter. RedrawPanel is called whenever a new Download starts. When I press button on Panel (generated from RedrawPanel), how do I send the token so it stops any further Download calls?

Comment: We can't answer this question unless you post a [mcve]. We need all the relevant code. You need to spend the time to create an example that simply shows the problem you have. Does that make sense?